# LAMP to Django; is it wise to use the admin as the website proper?

Tags: php, mysql, django

I need to port a CMS (to be sold and needing a certain look and feel) originally written in PHP and using a mysql database on Django. While researching this framework, I found that the default admin has all the base qualities I need. Now comes the difficult question; is it wise to use the default admin (styling it for the project's needs (i.e Django-jet)), or should I create all the pages needed individually (using metronics, for example) and leave the admin as is?

Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends strictly upon project needs. If you do not want to spend too much time in building it from scratch thats fine you can control user access in admin panel using permissions and groups. In the past I have used Django Admin panel as is for my clients and they never cared.

But If its a big project with 10s of models and lots of users using admin panel, then its worth creating it from scratch.

With upgrade in Django 2.0 admin panel is responsive as well, and using packages like DJango-jet completely removes the need for creating admin view from scratch.

Comment: ok, thank you for the fast answer. I actually have 10s of models. The project is for managing a company (from stock count to bills) while also having CRM functionalities as well as providing statistics. For a user-friendly experience, I frequently use Jquery and Ajax. Is it better then to build it from the ground up?

Comment: That looks pretty big to me. I would develop admin interface from scratch. But Again using django's admin interface has no cons. Its just personal preference.

Comment: It also depends upon how good you are with django, sometimes customizing django admin would require more knowledge than building it from scratch